# One button running all events

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know this is a silly question but I can't find a simple answer on internet. 

If I have more than one button on my asp.net website and click one of them it tries to run all the buttons at once.

For example I have a sign up form and a search bar on one page when the user clicks search button it tries to run the sign in button code too.  They are both in different validation groups and I know it has to be something simple but cant figure it out.

Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The best way we can help is to see some code....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly want, but I think you want to execute two or more buttons.
here are two solutions:
First one to handle all the events in one sub routine:

```
Protected Sub ButtonsHandler_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click, btnSignup.Click, btnOther.Click
    Dim btnAll As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    If btnAll Is btnSignup OrElse btnAll Is btnSearch Then
        'Signup code.
    End If

    If btnAll Is btnSearch Then
        'Search code.
    End If

    If btnAll Is btnOther Then
        'Other code.
    End If
End Sub
```

The second solution to create function for each functionality and call it from the button:

```
   Private Sub Search()
        'Search code.
    End Sub

    Private Sub Signup()
        'Signup code
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Signup()
        Search()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSignup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignup.Click
        Signup()
    End Sub
```